# How to convert class of several variables at once

Tags: r, dplyr

So I have a data frame with several variable that are characters that I want to convert to numeric. Each of these variables starts with "sect1". I can do this easily one at a time, but I'm wondering if this can be accomplished all at once.

I've done this in a clunky way using the following code. Maybe there's a better way?

```
df=data.frame(sect1q1=as.character(c("1","2","3","4","5")),
sect1q2=as.character(c("2","3","4","7","8")),id=c(22,33,44,55,66),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1 = sapply(select(df,starts_with("sect1")),as.numeric)
df = select(df,-starts_with("sect1"))
df =cbind(df,df1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `mutate_each` and (as per @Franks comment the `%<>%` operator from the `magrittr` package in order to modify *in place*)

```
library(magrittr)
df %<>% mutate_each(funs(as.numeric), starts_with("sect1"))
str(df)
# 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ sect1q1: num  1 2 3 4 5
# $ sect1q2: num  2 3 4 7 8
# $ id     : num  22 33 44 55 66
```

Alternatively, using `data.table` package, you could modify your data *in place* using the `:=` operator

```
library(data.table)
indx <- grep("^sect1", names(df), value = TRUE)
setDT(df)[, (indx) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = indx]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an solution with base R

`df[, grepl("sect1", names(df))] <- lapply(df[, grepl("sect1", names(df))], as.factor)`

Change `as.factor` to `as.numeric` for numeric

Comment: I had a solution in base R, it just got VERY ugly trying to keep all the brackets and parentheses straight.